# jQuery how to bind & unbind to window but attach to an element?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm building a dropdown menu. When you click the arrow the dropdown opens.

When the menu is open I want to close the menu on menu item click or on document blur. But it doesn't seem like I want to bind the following as so:

```
$(document.body).bind('click',function(e) {
    if(menuopen) {
```

As that would be tracking all clicks for just the menu. Is there a way to only have this bind working when the menu is open and unbind when the menu is closed?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
$(document.body).on("click blur", function () {
  $("div.dropdown.open").removeClass("open");
})

$("div.dropdown div.arrow").on("click", function () {
  $(this).closest("div.dropdown").addClass("open");
})
```

This is assuming that the adding the `.open` CSS class shows the menu, while removing it hides the menu.

*Note that `.on()` is available as of jQuery 1.7. Earlier versions use `.bind()` or `.delegate()` for the same effect.*

Comment: What does the "ul.dropdown.open" do?

Comment: It selects all `<div>` elements that have the both `dropdown` and the `open` CSS class. It's a way to track look *and* state of the element without having to resort to a global variable.

Comment: The first link will close the dropdown if you click inside the dropdown but it doesn't close if you click outside the dropdown anywhere else on the page? That's the problem? Ideas?

Comment: @AnApprentice: I've corrected my code, try again. — Also, it's *a little bit* difficult to get the selectors right without seeing your actual HTML. ;)

Comment: Thanks but this binds all ALL click and blurs on the page, I was hoping to avoid that by only having this binding take place when the dropdown was actually open,

Comment: @AnApprentice: That's right, but why would you care? The event handler does nothing when no menu is open. Unbinding it just because you're uncomfortable with a "no-op" doesn't make much sense to me. (the function call is plenty fast, you gain nothing by avoiding it)